# Modify array before storing in postgres database using enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, enums, database-migration

I am working on ruby on rails. I sending an array parameter from frontend like ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"]. Now, I want to automatically change this array to integer values like "Sunday" becomes 0, "Monday" becomes 1 and so on. I read about enum and active record in rails but they working with only string. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```rb
enum my_best_day: %i[sunday monday tuesday wedenesday friday saturday]
```

Now just store `MyClass.create(my_best_day: :monday)`

On database, it's stored as `1`. Create migration for this of course. Column `my_best_day` must be an `Integer` with default value to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I want to store integer array in database. Like, ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"] will store as [0,1,2] in database.
The above solution will only work for one string.

Comment: Then `enum` won't work. You got 2 options, `jsonb` or `t.string :your_column, array: true` (on your migration). Both need to be handled manually.